# is it possible to connect to java jOOQ DB?

Tags: jooq

I discovered a new interesting service and I'm trying to understand how it works. Please explain how to connect to my jOOQ database from another program?

```
MockDataProvider provider = new MyProvider();
MockConnection connection = new MockConnection(provider);
DSLContext create = DSL.using(connection, SQLDialect.H2);
Field<Integer> id = field(name("BOOK", "ID"), SQLDataType.INTEGER);
Field<String> book = field(name("BOOK", "NAME"), SQLDataType.VARCHAR);
```

So, I create but can I connect to it?

Here I have added your code, Lukas.

```
try (Statement s = connection.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT ...")
) {
    while (rs.next())
        System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
}
```

This example was found here
https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.7/manual/tools/jdbc-mocking/

```
public class MyProvider implements MockDataProvider {

    @Override
    public MockResult[] execute(MockExecuteContext ctx) throws SQLException {

        // You might need a DSLContext to create org.jooq.Result and org.jooq.Record objects
        //DSLContext create = DSL.using(SQLDialect.ORACLE);
        DSLContext create = DSL.using(SQLDialect.H2);
        MockResult[] mock = new MockResult[1];
        
        // The execute context contains SQL string(s), bind values, and other meta-data
        String sql = ctx.sql();
        
        // Dynamic field creation
        Field<Integer> id = field(name("AUTHOR", "ID"), SQLDataType.INTEGER);
        Field<String> lastName = field(name("AUTHOR", "LAST_NAME"), SQLDataType.VARCHAR);
        
        // Exceptions are propagated through the JDBC and jOOQ APIs
        if (sql.toUpperCase().startsWith("DROP")) {
            throw new SQLException("Statement not supported: " + sql);
        }
        
        // You decide, whether any given statement returns results, and how many
        else if (sql.toUpperCase().startsWith("SELECT")) {
            
            // Always return one record
            Result<Record2<Integer, String>> result = create.newResult(id, lastName);
            result.add(create
                .newRecord(id, lastName)
                .values(1, "Orwell"));
            mock[0] = new MockResult(1, result);
        }
        
        // You can detect batch statements easily
        else if (ctx.batch()) {
            // [...]
        }
        
        return mock;
    }
}
```

Comment: _"Please explain how to connect to my jOOQ database from another program?"_ The code you show has nothing to do with that. Do you understand that mocking is for unit tests? Also, jOOQ is not a database, it is a library to query a database.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what lines 3-5 of your example are supposed to do, but if you implement your `MockDataProvider` and put that into a `MockConnection`, you just use that like any other JDBC connection, e.g.

```java
try (Statement s = connection.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT ...")
) {
    while (rs.next())
        System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
}
```

Comment: added where i found this example.

// Pass the mock connection to a jOOQ DSLContext:
DSLContext create = DSL.using(connection, SQLDialect.ORACLE);
// Execute queries transparently, with the above DSLContext:
Result<BookRecord> result = create.selectFrom(BOOK).where(BOOK.ID.eq(5)).fetch();
lines 4-5 here i tried my result to work , but it didnt

Comment: i have implemented MockConnection as in example. But i dont see that this is simulating connection. I have found only information that it can connect to existing DB

Comment: i have added implementation  of MockDataProvider if you can, please answer more fully to me to understand

Comment: java.sql.Statement s or org.jooq.Statement s?

Comment: i have impemented your code and the result is 1, i still dont understand how i can connect to my code by other program

Comment: @yndingo: I don't understand your question. So far, you've copy pasted the code from the manual (latest version here: https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/mocking-connection/). But what code did *YOU* write? Perhaps, re-phrase your question along the lines of what Stack Overflow suggests here? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: there is no my code. Just question how to do...
i am googling, thank you though

Comment: You said *"i have impemented your code and the result is 1"*, so you did write some code. I'm sorry, I don't really know what else to explain to you. The manual seems quite clear to me, and so does my example. But your question (and what you've tried so far) seem to hint at something entirely different. I'll be happy to answer a *specific* question about something, but "just explain things to me" is an endless endeavour...

Comment: i have edited my post and show where i have added your code.
Program compiled. System.out work

Comment: @yndingo: Oh, you've added *my* code? :) But have you thought about what this is doing? You're mocking the JDBC API via jOOQ. And you told the `MockDataProvider` to return a row of the form `(1, Orwell)` on *any* `SELECT`. That's what your code does. You can put breakpoints in it to help understand things. What else were you expecting? The code does what you told it to do. I still don't understand your question. Did you think this was magically a *real* database? No, it's a mock. That's the purpose. That's what it says in the manual, too...

Comment: Thank you! For now i dont understand what im doing. Im just like blind kitty. Its great mock! What i want - to know how to connect to it by other java program and get this result. Not other class, but other program that needs to create connection to this.

Comment: @yndingo: I already gave you that very answer.

Comment: may be u can explain it details please?